# LibreOffice: How to create popup menu in a form?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I design an application in LibreOffice Base 5.3 using forms and Star Basic macros.

Is it possible to create a custom context menu which popups on right mouse button click and is bound to datagrid in a form?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what you mean by popup (context) menu bound to a datagrid.  Do you mean something like a list box?

Comment: I mean a menu that appears after click the right mouse button. Currently appears the default LO Base menu with single "Copy" command. I'd like to add some custom commands to it (commands related to selected record in grid).